# DSE - com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

My Cassandra table has secondary indexes of type 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex'. They were created automatically when I initialized the Solr core so they are probably used by Solr in some way.

What exactly is their purpose? What is the effect if I cancel the index build in my Cassandra node? (but not in my Solr nodes)

Answer (score 1):

That index type doesn't cause any overhead on non-Solr nodes, so you don't have to (actually, you must not) drop them.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what purpose these indexes serve? (because my boss is asking why we have indexes in Cassandra when we plan to do all reads via Solr). Also, I'm not asking about dropping the indexes. Rather, I'm interested about the effect of cancelling the secondary index build in the Cassandra node (i.e why is it building an index anyway when it's not a Solr node?)

Comment: Solr-based indexes are built on top of per-row Cassandra secondary index APIs, so that's why you see those indexes in your table; practically speaking, they're invoked to index rows when column values change, but they're no-op on non-Solr nodes.

Speaking about your index build, how did you fire it? Solr indexes should be rebuilt via the Solr HTTP APIs (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchReldCore.html?scroll=srchReldCore__srchReIndx); if you used nodetool, then yes you can cancel it and start a proper reindex via HTTP.

Comment: The index build is triggered whenever I load data via sstableloader or whenever I do repair. Unfortunately, my Cassandra DC contains much less nodes than my Solr DC so each Cassandra node handles more data and hence they always finish last (i.e. they slow down the whole process). I'm wondering how no-op the index build in non-Solr nodes is. If it is indeed no-op, shouldn't it finish in less than a second? That's not the case for me

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is their purpose?

Solr extends the search possibilities of Cassandra rows. Therefore, it allows Cassandra nodes to have the 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex' rows automatically and **asynchronously** indexed on Solr whenever you insert/update a row.

In addition Solr provides a HTTP interface (http://:8983/solr) that allows you to reload/rebuilt the index, among other admin Solr tasks.